# having problem creating ScrollView with TextView inside ImageView

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

I want to create a `scrollview` including several `imageviews` that have some `textviews` inside them. like in the picture.

I tried to do this with `constraintlayout` and using `sdp`, but when the size of the screen even slightly changes, it gets messy.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please share your xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sdf"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Text1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Text1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

If you want now to add more of these into your `ScrollView` do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //ADD VIEWS HERE

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can add them manually or programmatically. The result is this:

[image]